# Angular route not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I'm attempting to setup some basic routes in my Angular app but cannot seem to get `ngView` to work correctly. Below is my relevant index.html code, module, and config:

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <h3>Testing is live</h3>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

app.module.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
```

app.config.js:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/player/:playerId',
      {
        template: '<h1>testing...</h1>',
        controller: 'PlayerInfoController',
        controllerAs: 'playerInfo'  
      }
    );

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false,
      rewriteLinks: false
    });
  });
```

When I visit `/player/56` for example, I see 'Testing is live', but not 'testing...' as I would expect. Instead there's simply `<!-- ngView: -->` in that section.

Comment: Just FYI, from what you've posted, you're declaring the module 'myApp' twice. If you want to create a new module you use the array and pass in your dependencies.  When you just want to reference that module, don't use the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made two changes to the above code to get it working, but I do not fully understand why this was necessary; it seems like a "hacky" fix to me.

In my config file:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false,
  rewriteLinks: false
});
```

was replaced with:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and I added the following to the `head` of my index.html file:

```
<base href="/player">
```

Comment: Seems like you've read the same tutorial as I did. You solved one problem of mine.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the double declaration issue, can you tell if the route is being hit at all? Would a console.log in that PlayerInfoController be called in your chrome developer tools console when you navigate to that route? Or do you receive an error of any kind?

Comment: The console.log never fires, so it appears my controller never runs for that route. Also, there is no error message.

Comment: Are you including the file in your index.html file that gets loaded? Each angularjs file needs to be loaded separately. So you'd need a script tag the file that contains your app.js and a script tag that loads your config file.

Comment: Yes, the necessary files are included in index.html. I just left them out of the code I posted to keep my post concise.

Comment: Glad to see you found a solution that works. Sorry I couldn't be of any more help! I'm more familiar with Angular's UI-Router (which I would totally suggest! :) )

Comment: I agree with you completely. The project in question has existed with the built-in Angular router for awhile. I may refactor it to use UI-Router some day if time permits.